# How to semantically mark up an utility bar and main navigation in a e-commerce website?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup, wai-aria

This is the markup I have written for the header of web commerce site. I am not sure if it is semantically correct - especially the utility bar. Should I add the `role`-`navigation` to the container `div` of the links to the account, wishlist pages or should that also be within a `nav` element or an `aside`?

Also please let me know what I can do to make THIS design (can't change the order of the design - client wants it like this) more accessible and friendly towards assistive technologies.

```
<header>

  <div role="navigation" aria-labelledby="utility-nav" class="utility-nav">
    <h2 class="visuallyhidden" id="utility-nav">Account and store pages</h2>
      <div class="align-right">
        <a href="#">my account</a>
        <a href="#">find a store</a>
        <a href="#">credit center</a>
        <a href="#">track order</a>
        <a href="#">wishlist</a>
      </div>
  </div>  <!-- utility bar -->

  <div id="logo-search">

   <!-- logo -->
   <!-- search -->
   <!-- mini cart/shopping bag -->

  </div> <!-- logo, search, shopping bag container -->     

  <nav id="top-nav">
    <a href="#">Women</a>
    <a href="#">Men</a>
    <a href="#">Juniors</a>
    <a href="#">Baby</a>
    <!-- etc -->              
  </nav>  <!-- top nav -->

</header> <!-- header -->
```

Comment: You say you want to make THIS design (all-caps), but I am not sure if there is a design you were intending to link there.

Comment: Adding the design would make things much clearer but I am afraid that would breach the NDA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `<div role="navigation">` just use `<nav>`. It is ok to have more than one `<nav>` element on the page, even in a `<header>`. While `<nav>` is generally reserved for major blocks of navigation (meaning realistically you would max out at two or three on a page), I think both of these qualify in your example.

Consider putting your links within a list as that announces the number of items to a screen reader user.

Also, I suspect your `visuallyhidden` class is there to hide the `<h2>` from all users except screen readers. Pairing that with `aria-labelledby` results in it being announced twice. Having the `<h2>`can also create unnecessary stops in heading navigation within a screen reader. Consider dumping the `<h2>` altogether and using `aria-label` instead. This way you don't need to visually hide it and you can still provide context to your screen reader users.

At that point, you might want to also do that to the primary navigation (or not, depending on user testing and how verbose it makes the page).

So, to tweak your example a bit:

```
<header>
 <nav aria-label="Account and store pages" class="utility-nav">
   <ul class="align-right">
    <li><a href="#">my account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">find a store</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">credit center</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">track order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">wishlist</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>  <!-- utility bar -->

 […]

 <nav aria-label="Primary navigation" id="top-nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Juniors</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Baby</a></li>
 <!-- etc -->
  </ul>        
 </nav>
</header>
```

If you can, consider downloading the [free screen reader NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org/) (and donating if your employer has the cash) and running it through the page you build.

Comment: Thanks you! I avoided putting the links in the nav because of the argument made [here](https://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/#reinhard) by Reinhard Stebner who is visually impaired.

Comment: I think some user testing will resolve the links in lists question. From experience, different screen reader users report different levels of helpfulness (or lack). His point seems to be that there is no indication _which_ list of links you are in on pages with lots of links, but the `aria-label` might mitigate that for him. Either way, test.